# 80s or early 90s sci-fi/horror possibly a spoof movie

Tags: story-identification, movie, frankensteins-monster

I can’t remember much of this movie, but it’s driving me crazy. I remember watching it at my dads on a recorded VHS tape from one of my brothers.

Now I’m gonna jump around and just describe the few things I remember.

The movie is sometimes in black in white because the young man has a necklace (I think) that allows him to travel through different stories or times. One of them was the story of Frankenstein. I remember in one scene he finds a deformed monster boy chained up, and the townspeople are after them with torches and pitchforks.

One scene that is revisited every time he travels back to present time has a man (comedian) who looks like Al Lewis with white hair chained to a wall where his body cavity is exposed from someone throwing acid on him. At one point the man gets knocked over getting rocks in his ribs. This part is like a comedy, it has the guy chained up being pecked at by crows and he’s yelling at the birds.

Sorry this is all over the place, but does any of this sound familiar?

The guy is searching for a girl in the movie, he’s trying to save her from someone but I can’t remember who exactly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like the horror-comedy *[Waxwork II: Lost in Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waxwork_II:_Lost_in_Time)*. The premise is the man looking for evidence of the supernatural he can bring back to prove that a zombie hand committed the murder his girlfriend is accused of.

Ironically enough, I just picked up the collected version of the two films a few weeks ago.